# What's the best way to nmap thousands of subnets in parallel from a script?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, nmap

To inventory a port in part of a Class-A network, I scan that as a few thousand Class-C networks using nmap.  I use parallel to run 32 subnet scan jobs at once.

A minimized version of the script:

```sh
while read subnet; do
    echo nmap -Pn -p"$tcpport" "$subnet" >> /tmp/nmap_parallel.list;
done < $subnets
parallel -j32 < /tmp/nmap_parallel.list
wait
echo "Subnet scan for port $tcpport complete."
```

Problem with this approach is the script stops at parallel.

Is there a better way to use parallel from a script?

Comment: @konsolebox Nmap is not a blackhat tool. It is a valid network discovery tool used by thousands of network admins on a daily basis.

Comment: @bonsaiviking I know it is.

Answer (score 3):

Nmap has built-in parallelism that should be able to handle scanning a Class-A network in a single command. In fact, because of Nmap's network status monitoring and feedback mechanisms, it is usually better to run just one instance of Nmap at a time. The bottleneck for Nmap is not the processor, so running multiple instances with `parallel` is not going to help. Instead, Nmap will send many probes at once and wait for responses. As new responses come in, new probes can be sent out. If Nmap gets a response for every probe, it increases the number of outstanding probes (parallelism) it sends. When it detects a packet drop, it decreases this number (as well as some other timing-related variables).

This adaptive timing behavior is discussed at length in the [official *Nmap Network Scanning* book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0979958717), and is based on public algorithms used in TCP.

You may be able to speed up your scan by adjusting some [timing options](http://nmap.org/book/man-performance.html) and eliminating scan phases that do not matter to you. On the simple end, you can try `-T4` to increase several timing-related settings at once, without exceeding the capability of a high-speed link. You can also try adding `-n` to skip the reverse-DNS name lookup phase, since you may not be interested in those results.

You have already used the `-Pn` flag to skip the host discovery phase; if you are only scanning one port, this may be a good idea, but it may also result in confusing output and slower scan times, since Nmap must assume that every host is up and do a real port scan. Remember the adaptive timing algorithms? They have slightly different behavior when doing host discovery that may result in faster scan times. If you don't like the [default host discovery probes](http://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html), you can tune them yourself. If I am scanning for port 22, I can use that as a host discovery probe with `-PS22`, which means my output will only show hosts with that port open or closed (not firewalled and not down). If you stick with `-Pn`, you should probably also use the `--open` option to only show hosts with your chosen ports open, otherwise you will have a *lot* of output to slog through.

Comment: Often, people will suggest that Nmap use threads or some other CPU parallelism mechanism to speed up scans. [This article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-infinite-space-between-words/) is a fantastic illustration of why that doesn't really matter in a network scanner.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I simplified the script above, in practice I output to an XML file, convert to JSON and ingest JSON into a database.

Comment: Let me expand on the above comment - If I simply use -iL for the subnet list and use a 1-liner job, the output file would be huge and wouldn't be generated for a half-day.  I also see a huge performance difference between 'parallel -j4 < nmap_command_list' and 'parallel -j32 < nmap_command_list' most likely due to generating the output file (-oX subnet_port.xml).  I also use the --open flag.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you send the commands to the background with & in order to process the others simultaneously? Something like below;

```
#!/bin/bash
ports="20 21 22 25 80 443"
for p in $ports
do
nmap -Pn -p$p 10.0.1.0/24 &
done
```

Comment: This is really a nice simple approach that allows the kernel and cpu to handle the queuing and availability of cores / threads. Always KISS - Keep It Simple Stupid. Thank you.