# How do I make nmap run faster?

Tags: python, networking, ip, port, nmap

So I know this is an odd piece of code. I am simply trying to make nmap run faster. I need to find all active ips and what ports are open on the 10.0.0.0/8 network. My company has very poor documentation and never kept track of all this. I have a lot of cores to work with on my machine, but nmap doesn't make use of them. I also have a 10 gig NIC. I should be able to make this go blazing fast if I did it right, but I am not sure how to go about it. My code below is one of many attempts to multithread calls to nmap, but it seems os.system() puts a pause on everything else. Obviously that won't help make my scans run faster.

Eventually I need to use -Pn since some of the hosts have ICMP disabled, but might have open ports. Since my boss won't accept waiting 11 years for this I am kind of stuck. Any help, advice, or scolding for doing it completely wrong would be much appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

```
import os
import sys
from threading import Thread

def nmaping(x):
    command = "nmap 10." + str(x) + ".0.0/16 --open -oG nmap10-" + str(x) + ".txt"
    print(command)

try:
    threads = []
    
    for x in range(0, 255):
        t = Thread(target = nmaping, args=(x,))
        t.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Quit")
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Check masscan project https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989105/whats-the-best-way-to-nmap-thousands-of-subnets-in-parallel-from-a-script/24994879#24994879 you don't want to run multiple nmap commands. Also try using parameters `nmap 10.0-255.0.0 -Pn -n -sS --open -oG nmap-results.txt`

Comment: This is a great tool thanks. It will definitely give me a start, but I think I still need more. Is there a way to run masscan on all ports? I need to build a map of every open port, so I need to run it on all possible ports.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it to work, and I figured I would answer my own question so people in the future can find it.

masscan was the answer. I was able to narrow down the ports that mattered and I got the entire subnet done.

There is a major problem though. Don't ever do this!!! I ddos'd our firewall by running it too fast. It took down our network for a while.

If anyone else ever needs to do this do this slower. --max-rate 10000000 is way too high.

Thank you for the help otherwise Benoit Zu

Answer (score 0):

Masscan is still faster port scanning tool:

https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan

Or if you still want to use Nmap, you can bind it with GNU parallel. Better for scanning services using nmap which Masscan doesn't do at the moment.